# toomanyrequests: Rate exceeded on ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

Recently we are facing rate-limiting issues on ECR, error is `toomanyrequests: Rate exceeded`, 
We have a docker image with ~40 layer when we do a docker push some time total api transactions will be 40-15 but some time it will be 100-150 transactions. 
Why this scenario occurs as image layer nothing is changed but api transactions like `InitiateLayerUpload` differs in huge amount

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried logging into the public ecr?

```sh
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws
```

See documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-registries.html#public-registry-auth